# WINS is installed under Add/Remove Windows Components, but the service doesn't show up under Services?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs, wins

On a Windows Server 2003 for Small Business Server, the WINS server is installed under Add/Remove Windows Components, but the Windows Internet Naming Service doesn't show up in the Services list.

Do I need to install something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WINS snap-in in mmc.exe to manage it if it's installed correctly. A reboot is necessary after the install, which may be why you're not seeing it.

Here is a fairly complete guide to setting up a WINS server: http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-server-2003/how-to-install-a-wins-server-in-win-server-2003/

EDIT: Corrections.

Comment: Yes, I know.  However, when I go to the snap-in, if I click on Server Status it says "There are no items to show in this view" and if I use the Action menu to add itself as a server, it says it cannot be located, and the error is: "The Windows Internet Naming Service is not running on the target computer".  When I look in services, I notice that's true... the service doesn't even show up.  From what I can tell, there should be a service called "Windows Internet Naming Service".

Comment: Have you rebooted since installing WINS?

Comment: If a reboot doesn't fix it, try uninstalling and reinstalling WINS.

Comment: I don't know if it's been rebooted since.  I wasn't the one to install it.  However, it's been around a long time.

Comment: I tried rebooting, and the service still doesn't show up.  I'll have to try re-installing.

Comment: Resolution: uninstalling and re-installing WINS worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...